# Jquery setTimeout is making issues and not working properly in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I am working on below code snippet. Without setTimeOut(), its working perfect and displaying me the id in loaded(id) function. But with setTimeOut() this is not working properly.

```
var menuLink = document.getElementsByClassName("li_common_class");
        for(var i = 0; i <  5; i++ ) {
            var childElement = menuLink[i];
            childElement.addEventListener('click',setTimeout(function(){
                loaded(childElement.id);
            },100), true);
        }
    function loaded(id){
     alert(id);
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to add a setTimeout function when the user clicks on your childElement?

Comment: what does jQuery have to do with this? No jQuery code shown. Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: define what is not working properly?.

Comment: Use `...for(var i = 0; i <  menuLink.lengh; i++ ) {...`

Comment: You're invoking `setTimeout` immediately instead of passing a function that triggers it. Also, you'll hit the *closure in a loop* problem since you declared `childElement` with `var` instead of `let` or `const`

Answer (score 1):

***Passing a function***

You should be assigning an event handler, but instead you're *invoking* `setTimeout` immediately.

Pass a function to `.addEventListener()`, and use `const` to declare the variable.

```
var menuLink = document.getElementsByClassName("li_common_class");

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  const childElement = menuLink[i];

  childElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      loaded(childElement.id);
    }, 100)
  }, true);
}

function loaded(id) {
  alert(id);
}
```

So now that pass a function as the second argument to `.addEventListener`. That function gets assigned as the event handler for the child element. I also declared `childElement` using `const`, otherwise you'd always get the *last* value assigned to that variable instead of the respective value for each loop iteration.

---

***Eliminating the need for a closure reference***

However, this still isn't ideal. You really don't need `childElement` at all, since you have a reference to the element inside the handler already.

```
var menuLink = document.getElementsByClassName("li_common_class");

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  menuLink[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var targ = event.currentTarget
    setTimeout(function() {
      loaded(targ.id);
    }, 100)
  }, true);
}

function loaded(id) {
  alert(id);
}
```

See now that I added an `event` parameter to the handler function. This lets you grab the element to which the handler was bound.

We could have used `this` instead of `event.currentTarget`, but we actually lose that value inside the `setTimeout` callback. If we passed an arrow function to `setTimeout`, then the event handler's `this` would be reachable.

---

***Reusing the function***

But since there's no longer any need for a function to be associated with each iteration of the loop, we can actually move the function outside the loop, so that we're reusing it.

```js
var menuLink = document.getElementsByClassName("li_common_class");

for (var i = 0; i < menuLink.length; i++) {
  menuLink[i].addEventListener('click', handler, true);
}

function handler(event) {
  var targ = event.currentTarget

  setTimeout(function() {
    loaded(targ.id);
  }, 100)
}

function loaded(id) {
  alert(id);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="li_common_class" id="foo">CLICK ME</li>
  <li class="li_common_class" id="bar">CLICK ME</li>
  <li class="li_common_class" id="baz">CLICK ME</li>
</ul>
```

---

***ES6***

The same code can be greatly shortened if we are to use ES6:

```
const menuLinkOnClick = event => setTimeout(() => alert(event.target.id), 100),
      menuLinks       = document.getElementsByClassName("li_common_class");

for (let menuLink of menuLinks) {
  menuLink.addEventListener('click', menuLinkOnClick);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var menuLink = document.getElementsByClassName("li_common_class");
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      var childElement = menuLink[i];
      (function (ce) {
          ce.addEventListener('click', function () {

              setTimeout(function () {
                  loaded(ce.id);
              }, 100);

          }, true);
      })(childElement);

  }
  function loaded(id) {
      alert(id);
  }
```

Comment: Closure within a loop, would always alert id of last element 5

Comment: Give an explanation of your answer. You're not telling them what was wrong, how you fixed it, and what that IIFE syntax does, which will certainly be very confusing to a beginner.

Comment: I've updated my code. JavaScript has a concept called  **closure** you can find it here http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/.

Comment: it's just about variable scope.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var menuLink = document.getElementsByClassName("li_common_class");
for(i = 0; i <  5; i++) {
  var childElement = menuLink[i];
  childElement.addEventListener('click', function(){setTimeout(function(){loaded(childElement.id)},100)}, true);
}
function loaded(id){
  alert(id);
}
```

You had a function (setTimeout) in the addEventListener() without having it inside "" or function(){}. You need it in one of those except if you want it to call a function woth no parameters by putting functionName with no quotes, or ().

Hope this works.